# Tossing 2 Coins, Fair coin and a two headed coin

Tags: probability, probability-theory

There are two coins. One is two headed coin, the other one is a fair coin. A coin is selected randomly and flipped.

a) what is the probability of selecting a fair coin?

b) what is the probability of head from the flipped coin?

c) what is the probability of selecting a fair coin and having head on the top?

So A and B are relatively simple, because A is $1/2$ and for B its $3/4$
but I am concerned with C

Shouldn't be the chance of having a fair coin $+$ head
is basically $1/4$? Correct me if I am wrong but

If I want to pick a fair coin, the probability is $0.5$, lets say we picked it, and now we are going to throw it, isn't also chance between head and tail is $0.5$?
Which effectively means that getting a head from a fair coin

the intersection between them is $0.5\times0.5$ which equals $0.25$?

Comment: Is the answer to the c part, 1/3?

Comment: @Arsenic $P(A\land B)=P(A|B)P(B)$ so the probability of getting the fair coin and getting a head is the probability of getting a head, given that we have a fair coin ($\frac{1}{2}$), times the probability of getting a fair coin which is also $\frac{1}{2}$ so we get $\frac{1}{4}$. If we chose a coin, flipped it and got a head then the probability that the head came from the fair coin is $\frac{1}{3}$.

Comment: @Arsenic The prof didn't give us any answer or key sol 
I am sorry

Comment: @JohnDouma Yep! I presumed that the answer OP posted in the question was marked incorrect, so could only see conditional probability being a reason- which would have meant that the question wasn't framed correctly.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Let $F=$ "select a fair coin", and $H=$ "appear head on top"

$$P(F\cap H)=P(H|F)\cdot P(F)=\frac{1}2\cdot\frac{1}2=\frac{1}4$$

Comment: Thank you so much!

Comment: You are most welcome! If the answer helps, please $\checkmark$ my answer :) @Eimon

Comment: Done ^ 
Thanks again

Comment: You are welcome!

Comment: It may help to consider that it doesn't matter what the unfair coin is. It could be a two-tailed coin or a teddy bear; you are selecting (1/2) and then flipping (1/2).

Comment: yes, it is true